# DevExpress MVC GridView: Multiple gridviews loaded via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

I have a page with multiple DevExpress gridviews which are late-loaded via ajax. The problem is that after each ajax load only the last-loaded gridview is functional, others are *dead*, i.e. sorting, filtering and paging is not working.

I've pinpointed the problem to the fact that on each ajax load a web-request is made to DXR.axd, which returns new global DevExpress JS objects (like `ASPx = new { };`) overwriting the old objects, which causes the previously-loaded grid to stop working (this *does not happen* if multiple gridviews are present at initial page load, each callback loads only grid content, no DXR.axd).

As a last resort I *could* load gridviews hosted in IFRAMEs which I guess would solve the problem, but it's messy (IFRAME sizing issues) and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved starting with version 12.1

See [this](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=S37603) thread for more information.